# How to stop position fixed before footer?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a floating box and I'd like to know how I can stop it from overlapping the footer div by stopping it on the main div where it is only allowed to go.

```
window.onload = function ()
{
    var scrolledElement = document.getElementById('scrolling_box');
    var top = scrolledElement.offsetTop;
    var listener = function ()
    {
        var y = scrolledElement.scrollTop || scrolledElement.scrollTop || window.pageYOffset;

        if (y >= top-25)
        {
            scrolledElement.classList.add('fixed');
        } else {
            scrolledElement.classList.remove('fixed');
        }
    };
    window.addEventListener('scroll', listener, false);
}
```

I'd like for it to stop at the main div, that is as followed:

```
<div class="outer">

    <div class="main">

        <div class="left">

        </div>

        <div class="right">

            <div class="scrolling_box">
                the box that is scrolled goes right here
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

    <div id="footer">
        Footer goes here
    </div>

</div>
```

I'd like it to be stopped at the main class, I have looked a lot of other tutorials and none that I could port it to plain javascript. I tried including the .stop() but it wound up being only for jQuery sadly. I could not replicated the issue in jsfiddle, sadly.

I tried using float:both, left and right but neither seemed to have worked at all.

Comment: Do you want a box moving up and down But which stop before Footer ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5BHJ7/ anything near to it if not specify exactly what you want

Comment: I'd like for it to stop before the black footer, as to how it is set in the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/5BHJ7/1/ , I've been trying to get it to stop before that for two days but nothing.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5BHJ7/2/ checkit out updated it is it

Comment: Thank you for your help but I don't really use jQuery, which is why it has been more difficult to get it working as plain javascript is a little bit more less informational from what I have seen.

Comment: Nothing much actually its simpler than javascript and does all the good things as well Its almost solved check it out

Answer (score 0):

[Almost Solved Check for Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5BHJ7/2/)

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var pos = $('#footer').offset();
    var top = pos.top;
     var pos1 = $('#scrolling_boxI').offset();
    var top1 = pos1.top
    //alert(top);
  if( $(window).scrollTop()<top-150-top1)
  {
    $("#scrolling_boxI").stop().animate({"marginTop": ($(window).scrollTop()) + "px", "marginLeft":($(window).scrollLeft()) + "px"}, "slow" );
  }
});
```

Comment: It's really nothing that I even seemed to try and make it work, the 300x150 box should stop above the black box that I posted in the fiddle. THank you for your help though.